# Combine Two hash in Puppet

Tags: puppet

i have 2 hash, and need to "combine" them to make a new ssh_authorized_key resource:

First hash contains all ssh keys

```
$ssh_keys = {
 'user1@192.168.14.47' => {
    type => 'ssh-rsa',
    key  => 'Key1',
 },
 'user2@192.168.18.10' => {
    type => 'ssh-rsa',
    key  => 'Key2',
  }
}
```

second hash contains the "deploys" of the keys and users

```
$deploys = {
    'user1@192.168.14.47' => { user => ["user3","user4"]},
    'user2@192.168.18.10' => { user => ["user3"]}
}
```

I want to "merge" this hashes so i can use create_resources

```
$newhash ={
    'user1@192.168.14.47' => {
    type => 'ssh-rsa',
    key  => 'Key1',
    user => ["user3","user4"]
 },
 'user2@192.168.18.10' => {
    type => 'ssh-rsa',
    key  => 'Key2',
    user => ["user3"]
  }
}

create_resources('ssh_authorized_key',$newhash)
```

how can i create the newhash? puppet do not have iteration which make this way to difficult

The data of the hashes eventually comes from foreman smart classes/variables

**Edit:**
This is on foreman 1.11.1 with puppet 3.8.7 in ubuntu 14.04

Comment: There are several ways to do this, but it depends on the version of Puppet you are using. What version are you using?

Comment: use hiera and define the type of hash merge type you want https://docs.puppet.com/hiera/3.1/lookup_types.html#hash-merge

Answer (score 4):

I'm not aware of a function for merging hashes built into the puppet language, but you can always use a [custom parser function](https://docs.puppet.com/guides/custom_functions.html) instead -- which would allow you to combine two or more hashes however you like, using pure ruby -- and it's really not as scary as it sounds.

Fortunately, one of these already exists in the [puppetlabs/stdlib](https://forge.puppet.com/puppetlabs/stdlib) module. Unfortunately, the function you need for this particular case is [not documented](https://tickets.puppetlabs.com/browse/MODULES-2483) in the README. Called `deep_merge`, it will merge nested hashes and you can find documentation in the [source](https://github.com/puppetlabs/puppetlabs-stdlib/blob/master/lib/puppet/parser/functions/deep_merge.rb) of the function itself.

I don't use foreman, so it's unclear to me if you'll need to install the puppetlabs/stdlib module, or if it's accessible with the default install. It's a common dependency for a large number of forge modules, so you might have it already. If not, the [foreman docs](http://theforeman.org/manuals/1.11/index.html#2.2PuppetManagement) explain how to install and add a puppet module to a node (I presume you'd just replace `saz/ntp` with `puppetlabs/stdlib` where referenced).

You can then `deep_merge` to your heart's content, as in ...

```
$ssh_keys = {
 'user1@192.168.14.47' => {
    type => 'ssh-rsa',
    key  => 'Key1',
 },
 'user2@192.168.18.10' => {
    type => 'ssh-rsa',
    key  => 'Key2',
  }
}

$deploys = {
    'user1@192.168.14.47' => { user => ["user3","user4"]},
    'user2@192.168.18.10' => { user => ["user3"]}
}

$merged = deep_merge($ssh_keys, $deploys)

notify { $merged: }
```

... which results in ...

```
Notice: { \
  "user1@192.168.14.47"=>{"type"=>"ssh-rsa","key"=>"Key1", "user"=>["user3", "user4"]}, \
  "user2@192.168.18.10"=>{"type"=>"ssh-rsa", "key"=>"Key2","user"=>["user3"]}}
```

Comment: Since Puppet 4.0.0, you can use the `+` operator for merging hashes, which is equivalent to the `merge` function from stdlib. But there is nothing for _deep_ merges yet, so the answer is still correct...